# Is this safe to eat?

Tags: safety

I am immunocompromised.

Is this safe to eat? https://emalm.com/?v=Fn4vm

Look at its texture. **I  DON'T KNOW IF IT IS RAW OR COOKED.**

What it is: 5 organic medium egg yolks + 80g organic cow butter. Stirred on LOWEST heat.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  I'm afraid we're going to need more than a 17s video to give you any advice on whether eggs are sufficiently cooked.  Maybe an actual recipe?

Comment: @FuzzyChef Thanks. Here's the actual recipe. I put ghee and yolks (both from the fridge) in the pan. On lowest heat, I keep stirring. That's all. After maybe 5 minutes, ghee stops being solid. After maybe 10 minutes, the mixture thickens as you can see in the picture

Comment: You should actually add that recipe to the question, which will let folks help you.

Comment: Hi, you seem to not know how food safety works. "Is it safe" is a short way of asking "can I prove that it fulfills all the conditions set by a food safety authority". If you cannot prove it, it is automatically unsafe. You already said that you don't know whether it is cooked - this already means that it is unsafe. It can only be safe if you *know* enough about it to prove that it is safe. We are closing as a duplicate of the temperature question because in theory, if it were safe, you would have found that out by proving that it reached the required temperature.

Answer (score 3):

The sauce you are making is essentially Hollandaise Sauce; you're mixing eggs with warm, clarified butter until they emulsify.

If you are immunocompromised in a way that makes foodborne pathogens super-risky, then you are right to be cautious.  Eggs in hollandaise are not fully cooked, and it is difficult to hit the [exact temperature (62C/145F) where the sauce is too hot for bacteria but not hot enough to curdle and break the sauce](https://rouxbe.com/tips-techniques/486-food-safety-of-hollandaise).

As such, you might want to consider [making your sauce with pastuerized eggs](http://www.safeeggs.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/recipes/hollandaise-sauce-recipe.html).